# What is the Castle at the end of time known as?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki-2021

In the *Loki* series we see that there is a castle at the end of time which was protected by Alioth. In that mysterious castle, we see that

> He Who Remains lives.

What is the name of that castle, name of a similar castle at the end of time in comics is also valid?

Comment: Does it have a café?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's repeatedly referred to as "*The Citadel at the End of Time*" (or just "*The Citadel*") in interviews with the show's staff.

> The Citadel at the End of Time exists on top of an asteroid. Speaking
> to Marvel.com, Farahani reveals the inspiration, “In the comics,
> there’s precedent for **the Citadel at the End of Time** being on an
> asteroid,” referring to THOR (1966) #245. “What I proposed, early on,
> was this idea that the entire building, all of the architecture, was
> carved in situ from the asteroid; there were no other building
> materials,” comparing it to carvings like Petra in Jordan. The Citadel
> at the End of Time would be all carved from this black stone with gold
> vein embellishments.
>
> Farahani recommends fans to rewatch the series and spot the citadel
> stone making its presence early on, pointing out that the statues in
> Judge Renslayer’s office, the front of the judge’s dais in the Time
> Court, and the elevator to the Time Keepers’ chamber, are all carved
> from the same stone. “This is the link from He Who Remains to the TVA
> — this rock that the whole place is quarried from,” says the
> production designer.
>
> The Citadel at the End of Time is meant to punctuate He Who Remains’
> position as “this sad, lonely figure rattling around a big empty
> space.” After all, the creator of the TVA had to stave off his other
> variants, culminating in the Mutiversal War. Achieving cosmic harmony
> is an arduous and solitary task. To reflect He Who Remains’ eons of
> isolation, Farahani remarks, “The thinking with the Citadel was that
> it was in ruins except for the office. He retreated from all the
> different parts of the Citadel, abandoned them, and just holed up in
> his office.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Loki: Deconstructing He Who Remains’ Life’s Work at the Citadel at the End of Time](https://www.marvel.com/articles/tv-shows/loki-he-who-remains-citadel-end-of-time-kang-statue)</sup></sub>

---

Interestingly, the structure seen in [Thor Vol.1 #245](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor_Vol_1_245) (mentioned above) was not the *'citadel'* at the end of time, but rather a temple, hence the name of the story

> "***The Temple at the End of Time!***".
>
> [image]

Answer (score 10):

It is known as The Citadel at the End of Time. Loki actually calls it that in the episode as does Miss Minutes when they arrive:

> **Miss Minutes:** Welcome to The Citadel at the End of Time.
>
> <sub>*Loki*, Season 1 Episode 6, “For All Time, Always”</sub>

> **Loki:** We freed the Timeline. We found him beyond the storm. A Citadel at the End of Time. He's terrifying. He planned everything. He's seen everything. He knows everything.
>
> <sub>*Loki*, Season 1 Episode 6, “For All Time, Always”</sub>